# Convert an int to hex and then pad it with 0's to get a fixed length String

Tags: string, go, hex, type-conversion

I'm having some issues on trying to convert an `int` to hex then, padding it with `0`s in order to get a `6 Characters String` which represents the hex number.

So far, I tried the following:

```
intNumber := 12
hexNumber := strconv.FormatInt(intNumber, 16) //not working
```

And then I found out how to pad it with `0`s, using `%06d, number/string`. It makes all the strings 6 characters long.

[Here you can Find a Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lEYcu-dfiM) which I set up to make some tests.

**How can I achieve this in a efficient way?**

For any Clarifications on the question, just leave a comment below.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import "fmt"

hex := fmt.Sprintf("%06x", num)
```

The `x` means hexadecimal, the `6` means 6 digits, the `0` means left-pad with zeros and the `%` starts the whole sequence.

Comment: Almost what I'm looking for, except for the fact that I'm looking for a `6 Characters Long String which represents an Hex`. I guess I need to change `%016x` with `%06x` and it'll be ok.

Comment: I changed it, too.

Comment: @RolandIllig: How can I replace the 6 with a const variable? For example, const TOPIC_LENGTH = 6 ?

Comment: @HoangTrinh Just read [the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt), you will find the answer there, plus several more details that may prove useful in the future.